# Book where a guy is on the run after a routine hospital check-up shows metal in his stomach

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I can't find this book where a twenty-something-year-old is pursued after his normal hospital check-up shows metal workings inside his stomach. When he decides to run, he meets this girl who does fake IDs. Afterward, they go on the run together to the Canary Islands (I believe) and they fall in love. In the end, they're found and she dies, and he again goes on the run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds alot like *[Being](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/636199.Being)* by Kevin Brooks, published in 2007.

[image: Cover of "Being" showing the left half of a face, cut off by the left edge of the cover. The face is fair-skinned and has a brown eye. The person is wearing a black shirt.]

The Goodreads synopsis mentions the hospital check-up, where the main character, Robert, is found to have moving metal parts in his innards:

> "The Fugitive" meets "Blade Runner" with a Kevin Brooks kick in this heart-stopper about a boy who discovers he's not one hundred percent human.
>
> **It was just supposed to be a routine exam. But when the doctors snake the fiber-optic tube down Robert Smith's throat, what they discover doesn't make medical sense. Plastic casings. Silver filaments. Moving metal parts**. In his naked, anesthetized state on the operating table, Robert hears the surgeons' shocked comments: "What the hell is that?"
> "It's me," Robert thinks, "and I've got to get out of here." Armed with a stolen automatic and the videotape of his strange organs, he manages to escape, and to embark on an orphan's violent odyssey to find out exactly who--exactly what--he is.

And [this review](http://knightingalereviews.blogspot.com/2015/08/being-by-kevin-brooks_17.html) mentions a female supporting character named Eddi, who makes a living creating fake IDs:

> After running from the hospital with a stolen pistol, clothing, his medical files, his endoscopy video, and a hostage (who happens to be the anesthesiologist), Robert heads for the train station. He has no idea where he's going from there, what he is, or how he will escape those who will soon be coming after him. He abandons the hostage, hops on a train, and formulates a plan. **He will have to reach Eddi, a girl he once met long ago while he was staying at one of many homes for orphans. Eddi is a dangerous thief that makes a living creating fake IDs**. Robert desperately needs a new identity and Eddi is his only hope. Robert can't go home, the people who want him back have framed him for murder, and thus his old life is completely destroyed.

Robert is apparently sixteen years old rather than twenty-something, though.

You can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Being/cUzmiDqpdWcC?hl=en&gbpv=0).